# wlan profile xml with user and password

Tags: xml, wifi

I need to put user and password directly in the configuration. Where do I put it? 
As I do this, what tags do I have to put in and where do I need to place these tags. 
This is a wpa2 enterprise network with MS-CHAP V2. And I want to connect everyone with the same login and password.

This is the configuration file:

```
-<WLANProfile>
 <name>eduroam</name>
-<SSIDConfig>
-<SSID>
 <hex>656475726F616D</hex>
 <name>eduroam</name>
 </SSID>
 <nonBroadcast>false</nonBroadcast>
 </SSIDConfig>
 <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
 <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
 <autoSwitch>false</autoSwitch>
-<MSM>
-<security>
-<authEncryption>
 <authentication>WPA2</authentication>
 <encryption>AES</encryption>
 <useOneX>true</useOneX>
 </authEncryption>
-<OneX>
 <cacheUserData>true</cacheUserData>
 <authMode>user</authMode>
-<EAPConfig>
-<EapHostConfig>
-<EapMethod>
 <Type>25</Type>
 <VendorId>0</VendorId>
 <VendorType>0</VendorType>
 <AuthorId>0</AuthorId>
 </EapMethod>
-<Config>
-<Eap>
 <Type>25</Type>
-<EapType>
-<ServerValidation>
 <DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>false</DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>
 <ServerNames/>
 </ServerValidation>
 <FastReconnect>true</FastReconnect>
 <InnerEapOptional>false</InnerEapOptional>
-<Eap>
 <Type>26</Type>
-<EapType>
 <UseWinLogonCredentials>false</UseWinLogonCredentials>
 </EapType>
 </Eap>
 <EnableQuarantineChecks>false</EnableQuarantineChecks>
 <RequireCryptoBinding>false</RequireCryptoBinding>
-<PeapExtensions>
 <PerformServerValidation>false</PerformServerValidation>
 <AcceptServerName>false</AcceptServerName>
 </PeapExtensions>
 </EapType>
 </Eap>
 </Config>
 </EapHostConfig>
 </EAPConfig>
 </OneX>
 </security>
 </MSM>
 </WLANProfile>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what product this configuration XML was actually configuring.

Comment: I have the same problem. It's a windows wifi profile file.